# Error while trying to ensureIndex on embedded field (key name must not contain ".")

Tags: node.js, mongodb

We've been using the mongodb/nodejs driver for a few years, and are currently upgrading our systems with the latest driver / mongodb database. Mostly everything went well, except for indexes.

We get an error when trying to use the `collection.ensureIndex`function to add indexes. It's my first question here so I'll try to be as detailed as possible. I haven't found any linked issue...

Here are our current versions:

- Node: v0.10.33
- Mongodb Driver: v2.0.5
- Mongodb database: v2.4.12

Here is a test sample:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  test = require('assert');
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:28888/test', function(err, db) {
  var collection = db.collection('ensureIndexEmbedded');
  // Create an index on the a field
  collection.ensureIndex( {"a.c":1}
    , {background:true, w:1}, function(err, indexName) {
      console.log(err);
      //test.equal(null,err);
      db.close();
  });
});
```

And the result of running the test:

```
$ node testindex.js
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
{ [MongoError: n/a]
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'n/a',
  ok: 1,
  n: 1,
  code: 14,
  errmsg: 'key a.c must not contain \'.\'',
  writeErrors: [ { index: 0, code: 14, errmsg: 'key a.c must not contain \'.\'' } ] }
```

Is there a possibility that the *warning* `js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension` is linked with this issue? Or is there anything wrong with the syntax used to create the index?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Weird. This worked fine when I tried it using the v2.0.5 driver and MongoDB 2.6.5.

Comment: Thanks Johnny, maybe then its just a compatibility issue between the driver and mongo versions.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still interested. The problem is with the default name that is being assigned to the index. Since it is being constructed out of field names, it contains a dot. You can simply explicitly name your index. Just add "name" field to options argument of ensureIndex function call and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar error message, with mongojs v2.4.0 and mongod v3.2.1.

I have this error when I try to create an index on a nested field, but the index already exists with different options. E.g. the `{"unique" : true}` option set. Again, the error message is just super confusing, because the same nested key with dot-notation succeeds in the following cases :

- if I try to create the (already existing) index with the same options
- if I try to create the missing index it succeeds

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested the same code with MongoDB 2.6.5 and indeed it works fine.
There seems to be a compatibility issue between the 2.0.5 driver and MongoDB 2.4.12

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still encountering this issue, even if you set the name manually as documented, like this

```
YourSchema.index({
  "a.c":1
}, { 
  name: 'a_new_manually_defined_name_for_this_index'
});
```

and you are still getting this error, `key a.c must not contain \'.\'`

you must manually delete any old existing indexes first. then the error goes away, and the new index gets created with the name that you defined.